# How does the table function work for combination of two vectors?

Tags: r

I have a two vectors and I am using table function with combination of two vectors.

```
ratings <- c("Worst","Worst","Bad","Bad","Good","Bad","Bad")
reviewers  <- c("Siskel","Siskel","Elbert","Elbert","Martin","Rowen","Martin")
f3 <- table(ratings,reviewers)
```

f3:

```
   ratings    Elbert    Martin    Rowen   Siskel   
   Bad        2          1           1      0   
   Good       0          1           0      0  
   Worst      0          0           0      2
```

If you consider column Elbert, it is showing as '2','0','0' for Bad, Good, worst and so on for other columns. I want to know how these values are generated.

Comment: `"Siskel"` appears twice, so all of the numbers in the Siskel column will add up to two; for those two appearances, the corresponding values in `ratings` are both `"Worst"`, so there are zero Bad, zero Good, and two Worst. That explains that column. This process is repeated for all values.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a question mark before the function, `?table()` you will be able to see the documentation. The first argument of `table()` is `...` which is defined as:

> one or more objects which can be interpreted as factors (including
> character strings), or a list (or data frame) whose components can be
> so interpreted. (For as.table, arguments passed to specific methods;
> for as.data.frame, unused.)

Try running either of these line, noting you get the same result as `table(ratings,reviewers)`

```
table(data.frame(ratings,reviewers)
```

or

```
table(tibble::tibble(ratings,reviewers))
```

The integers in a table are quite obviously counts at each combination of factor levels.

Explore the arguments to find additional ways of customizing the table. One you might find handy is the ability to rename the dimensions using the `dnn=` argument. Here is an example use:

```
table(ratings,reviewers, dnn=c('Movie scores', "Movie critics"))
```

Using `?` before a function in R is a great way to get started.